# I have a distributor that wont come out of my 87 Ford Ranger xlt 2.9 engine. Bolt is out .

Tags: distributor

Does the engine need to be at tdc on number one cylinder to align it so it will come out?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you twist the distributor with the bolt out?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not **need** to be at the no 1 position, but that is an easy way to make sure it goes back correctly.

The distributor can be corroded so it won’t move - some freeing juice and working it back and forth may be successful.